# Is there a word for major software developers?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there a word for major software developers? There are amateur developers who work alone, there are indie developers who work for small companies and then you have Adobe who is a major developer. Is there a word or adjective that's used to refer to them? I am wondering, for instance, how Microsoft refer to those major developers in their internal memos. There has to be some kind of word or phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure "Major software developers".  You sometimes call a publishing company a "house" so "Major software houses" is also possible.